# Iteration of for loop inside object

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to iterate my array using for loop and it's working good, Now if I want that to iterate that inside an object, how can I do that?

**Below is my code**

```js
for (let j = 0; j < sowing.seedSownDetails.length; j++) {
  this.myObj = {
    sowSeedInventoryId: sowing.seedSownDetails[j]?.inventoryId,
    quantity: sowing.seedSownDetails[j]?.quantity
  };
  console.log(this.myObj); //all the iterations work here
}

this.addComments = {
  sowingId: sowing.sowingId,
  cropId: sowing.cropId,
  seedDetails: [this.myObj], // i want all my iteration object inside this array

  seedSowingDate: sowing.sowingDate,
  comments: form.value.comments
};
```

**Expected output:**

```js
seedDetails: [
{object1},
{object2},....
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `this.myObj = [];` at top or inside `constructor` and modify your code as below

```
for (let j = 0; j < sowing.seedSownDetails.length; j++) {
      this.myObj.push({
        sowSeedInventoryId: sowing.seedSownDetails[j]?.inventoryId,
        quantity: sowing.seedSownDetails[j]?.quantity
      });
    }

    this.addComments = {
      sowingId: sowing.sowingId,
      cropId: sowing.cropId,
      seedDetails: this.myObj, // You will get array of objects here as expected

      seedSowingDate: sowing.sowingDate,
      comments: form.value.comments,
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a getter:

```
private get myObj() {
   for (let j = 0; j < this.sowing.seedSownDetails.length; j++) {
      const myObj = {
        sowSeedInventoryId: this.sowing.seedSownDetails[j]?.inventoryId,
        quantity: this.sowing.seedSownDetails[j]?.quantity
      };
    }

    return myObj;
}
```

and consume it just like:

```
this.addComments = {
   sowingId: sowing.sowingId,
   cropId: sowing.cropId,
   seedDetails: this.myObj, // consume here

   seedSowingDate: sowing.sowingDate,
   comments: form.value.comments,
};
```